# Is there an internal cooldown on the Reclamation rune for Mantra of Conviction?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

From [Diablo 3 Database](http://d3db.com/skill/i/mantra-of-conviction)

> You and your allies have a 30% chance to be healed for 279 - 341 Life when using melee attacks on an enemy under the effects of Mantra of Conviction

Does this skill have any sort of internal cooldown, or limit to how many times it can occur in any way?

In other words, can I gain the effect of this rune for any potential hit on an enemy? This would make melee AoE attacks with many targets quite effective for self healing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the AoE is a melee attack, it should trigger the effect.  Every hit should have a chance to activate it.

Comment: I was able to confirm this several times in game, by removing all regen and +life on hit gear. More than once it seemed to proc for upwards or 4 and 5 hits when several enemies were around.